# finding a element in a matrix with the minimum cost starting from one point

Tags: c++, algorithm, search

I have n*n matrix and I want to find the element from the matrix that has the minimum cost, the cost of a node meaning cost = Manhattandistance(startingnode,node) + costof(node) where starting node is a node in which perspective I am searching!

I did it just with 4 for loops and it works but I want to optimize it and I did something like a bfs: I used a queue and added first the starting node, after that in a while loop I pop ed the node from the queue and added to the queue all the elements around that node with the Manhatttan 1. I do this while the distance of the node that I just popped from the queue + the minimum price from the whole matrix (which I know from the start) is less than the minimum price that I have just found ( I compare the price of the node I just popped with min) if it's bigger I stop searching because the minimum node I found is the lowest possible value. The problem is this algorithm is to slow possibly because I use a std::queue? and it works in more time than the 4 for loops version. (I also used a flags matrix to see if the element I am inspecting when I add to the queue has been already added). The most time consuming block of code is the part I expand the node don't know why I just inspect if the element is valid I mean it's coordinates are less than n and bigger than 0 if ok I add the element to the queue!

I want to know how can I improve this or if it's another way to do it! Hope I was explicit enough.

this is the part of code that takes to long:

```
if((p1.dist + 1 + Pmin) < pretmincomp || (p1.dist + 1 + Pmin) < pretres){
                std::vector<PAIR> vec;  
                PAIR pa;
                int p1a=p1.a,p1b = p1.b,p1d = p1.dist;
                if(isok(p1a+1,p1b,n)){
                    pa.a = p1a + 1;
                    pa.b = p1b;
                    pa.dist = p1d + 1;

                    vec.push_back(pa);
                }
                if(isok(p1a-1,p1b,n)){
                    pa.a = p1a - 1;
                    pa.b = p1b;
                    pa.dist = p1d + 1;
                    vec.push_back(pa);
                }

                if(isok(p1a,p1b+1,n)){
                    pa.a = p1a;
                    pa.b = p1b + 1;
                    pa.dist = p1d + 1;
                    vec.push_back(pa);
                }
                if(isok(p1a,p1b -1 ,n)){
                    pa.a = p1.a;
                    pa.b = p1.b - 1;
                    pa.dist = p1d + 1;
                    vec.push_back(pa);
                }



                for(std::vector<PAIR>::iterator it = vec.begin();
                         it!=vec.end(); it++){
                    if(flags[(*it).a][(*it).b] !=1){
                        devazut.push(*it);
                        flags[(*it).a][(*it).b] = 1;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You need to separate this into paragraphs, maybe provide some pictures or code snippits. ATM all i see is a wall of text.

Comment: Maybe you can show some code?

Comment: In a general case where you don't know any special property about the matrix, you need to brute force all the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with a [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem), which can be efficiently solved with [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (if the graph is unweighted) or [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) - if you have some "knowledge" on the graph and can estimate how much it will "cost" you to find a target from each node.

Your solution is very similar to BFS with one difference - **BFS also maintains a `visited` set** - of all the nodes you have already visited. The idea of this `visited` set is that you don't need to revisit a node that was already visited, because any path through it will be not shorter then the shortest path you will find during the first visit of this node.

Note that without the `visited` set - each node is revisited a lot of times, which makes the algorithm very inefficient.

Pseudo code for BFS (with visited set):

```
BFS(start):
  q <- new queue
  q.push(pair(start,0)) //0 indicates the distance from the start
  visited <- new set
  visited.add(start)
  while (not q.isEmpty()):
     curr <- q.pop()
     if (curr.first is target):
        return curr.second //the distance is indicated in the second element
     for each neighbor of curr.first:
        if (not set.contains(neighbor)): //add the element only if it is not in the set
           q.push(pair(neighbor,curr.second+1)) //add the new element to queue
           //and also add it to the visited set, so it won't be re-added to the queue.
           visited.add(neighbot) 
  //when here - no solution was found
  return infinity //exhausted all vertices and there is no path to a target
```